# What is the difference between “my_app” and “my_app.apps.My_appConfig in the installed INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im new in Django and I would like to know what is the difference between `"my_app"` and `"my_app.apps.My_appConfig"` in the installed INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: It would help if you showed us some actual code.

Comment: If that is the only config, there is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Django loads an app, it loads so through an `AppConfig`. The `AppConfig` provides a "context" how to run the app. For example the name and label of the app, the default type for the primary key of a model if no primary key is specified. Things to do when the app is loaded and so on. These can be defined in the `AppConfig`.

You can load an app through a *dotted path* that leads to the `AppConfig`, so `'app_name.apps.MyAppConfig'`, then it will load the app through that config. If you only specify the name of the app, so `'app_name'`, then it will look for the right `AppConfig`.

If there is no `apps.py`, or that `apps.py` contains no subclass of `AppConfig`, it will just use `AppConfig` itself, which has logic to instantiate the app without any "extras". If there is at least one `AppConfig`, it will look for a subclass of `AppConfig` with `default = True`, by default `default = True`, so if there is a single `AppConfig`, and one did not set `default = False`, it will pick that one.

If there are multiple `AppConfig`s with `default = True`, it will raise an error, since then it is unclear what app config will be used. If *`MyAppConfig`* is thus the only subclass of `AppConfig` in `apps.py` and `default` is not set to `False` for that one `'app_name.apps.MyAppConfig'` and simply `'app_name'` are thus equivalent.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for this wonderful explanation. I understand anymore. Thank you again.